# R: Creating two date variables from a complete date

Tags: r, statistics

I have date recorded as: **Month/Day/Year or MM/DD/YYYY**

I would like to write code that creates two new variables from that information.

1. I would like a year variable alone
2. I would like to create a quarter variable
   The Quarter Variables would not be influenced by year. I would want this variable to apply to all years.

Quarter 1 would be January 1 - March 31 
Quarter 2 would be April 1 - June 30
Quarter 3 would be July 1 - September 30
Quarter 4 would be October 1 - December 31

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I cannot seem to get the nuance of how to do these functions in R.

Thanks,

Jared

Comment: Use `lubridate`, you can select elements of a date you have using it, which  will allow you to select the year, and the month to determine the quarter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments. I am trying to work through each example and I find that this is just not that user friendly. Each solution here I sure will work, but it comes back with an error each time I attempt it. One person mentioned that the code would change depending on how the data are formatted. I made the incorrect assumption that everyone would be aware that my date variable DtEpisode was a column. How does this impact how the code should be written?

Comment: as.character(cleandata$DtEpisode)

strptime(cleandata$DtEpisode,form=("%m/%d/%Y"))

So far I got this far...now I think all I need to do is create a new variable. I think I am stuck at this part.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `date` variable is of class `POSIX**` you could do:

```
#example date
date <- as.POSIXlt( "05/12/2015", format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

In order to return the year from a date `data.table` has already a function to do it and that is `year`:

```
library(data.table)
> year(date)
[1] 2015
```

As for the quarter it can easily be created from the function below (uses `data.table::month` that returns the number of a month):

```
quarter <- function(x) {
  rep(c('quarter 1','quarter 2','quarter 3','quarter 4'), each=3)[month(x)]
} 

> quarter(date)
[1] "quarter 2"
```

Comment: as.POSIXlt.date(DtEpisode, format='%m/%d/%Y')

Error in as.POSIXct(x) : object 'DtEpisode' not found

Comment: Reading your comments above, `DtEpisode` is a column (why would anyone know that it is a column?) so you should do: `as.POSIXlt(cleandata$DtEpisode, format='%m/%d/%Y')`.

Comment: Also, in order to use `quarter` with a vector of dates do: `sapply(cleandata$DtEpisode, quarter)` once the vector is of POSIXlt class.

Answer (score 0):

Using only the base packages:

Try formatting your dates with the strptime fxn, so that all dates are now in the Year-Month-Day format. This format constrains the each element of the date to be the same character length and in the same position. Look at the strptime documentation for the appropriate formatting argument.

```
date.vec<-c(1/1/1999,2/2/1999)
fmt.date.vec<-strptime(date.vec, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

With the dates in this format it is easy to extract the year, month, and day using the substring function

```
Year<-substring(fmt.date.vec,1,4)
Month<-substring(fmt.date.vec,6,7)
Day<-substring(fmt.date.vec,9,10)
```

With this information you can now generate your Quarter vector any number of ways. For example if a data.frame "df" has a Month column:

```
df$Quarter<-"Quarter_1"
df[df$Month %in% c("04","05","06"),]$Quarter<-"Quarter_2"
df[df$Month %in% c("07","08","09"),]$Quarter<-"Quarter_3"
df[df$Month %in% c("10","11","12"),]$Quarter<-"Quarter_4"
```

Comment: This is what I attempted: strptime(DtEpisode, "%m/%d/%Y")
Error in strptime(DtEpisode, "%m/%d/%Y") : object 'DtEpisode' not found

Comment: It is odd because it says that DtEpisode is not found, but I am looking right at it.

Comment: Sorry I am going to give this another shot first thing in the morning. I have a migraine that is setting in right now.

Comment: If DtEpisode is a vector and it is spelled right, your code should work, if DtEpisode is a column in a data.frame you need to specify the column. Can print the vector?  Also you should double check for NAs in the output after converting to identify errors or different formats in your data

Comment: It is in fact a column. How would that change the code.

Comment: if your data frame is saved in object df, and you have a column DtEpisode, strptime(df$DtEpisode, "%m/%d/%Y") should work.

Comment: as.character(cleandata$DtEpisode)

strptime(cleandata$DtEpisode,form=("%m/%d/%Y"))  

This worked now I get> df$Quarter<-"Quarter_1"
Error in df$Quarter <- "Quarter_1" : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> df[df$Month %in% c("04","05","06"),]$Quarter<-"Quarter_2"
Error in df$Month : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> df[df$Month %in% c("07","08","09"),]$Quarter<-"Quarter_3"
Error in df$Month : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> df[df$Month %in% c("10","11","12"),]$Quarter<-"Quarter_4"
Error in df$Month : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: so cleandata is your data frame, in my code example I am using df as a generic name for a data frame. Replace df with cleandata and your code should work. Be sure that the strptime function did not return any NA values which will happen if your dates have multiple formats. you can check this by using nrow(cleandata[is.na(cleandata$DTEpisode),]